# Responsive Design: Floating Blocks

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, dynamic-columns

I am curious how to do a specific effect I have seen...

http://hype.co.uk

that being how they get the third smaller column (resize your browser until it pops a third thin column into existence)... The reason this is interesting to me is because you'd think it was in its own column div but when you shrink down to 2 columns the small blocks reflow back into the main floated div list.

So my question... at a certain size, how is it pulling the smaller block elements out into its own column?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Look at their css (toward the bottom) and you'll see that they're using `media queries`. This is how you "respond" to a user changing the width of their browser. For something like this, they may just be clearing a floated element or any other number of things. I recommend you check out this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/

Here's a basic example to get you started. Resize the page to see the floated divs being changed:

CSS:

```
#pagewrap {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

#content {
    width: 290px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

#middle {
    width: 294px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 270px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    float: left;
}

/* for 700px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    #content {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }

    #middle {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    #sidebar {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="pagewrap">
<div id="content">
    CONTENT
</div>
<div id="middle">
    MIDDLE
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    SIDEBAR
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand media queries my question was specific to how they've pulled out the smaller blocks, which otherwise (or when smaller) are in the main flow of blocks, this to me would require a change in html not just css?

Comment: No. The `CSS` in their media queries are changing the appearance of said blocks. Look at their code, the HTML and the CSS. Here's another example: http://cheesetoast.co.uk/demos/responsive.html. In this example, you'll see that by default the main `div`'s have `float` set to `left`. As the browser resizes, those floats get set to `none`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry tptcat, I really do understand that - my question is how if for example you have 10 blocks, and blocks 3 and 8 are smaller, how are *just those ones* being put into their own column at the right? do you see? This cant be done with standard floats... Or if it can i'm missing something... In the inspector in safari, it shows the style changing when resizing but it looks like absolute positioning which surely isn't the right way of doing it...

Comment: Aaaaahhhhh - its using isotope, I get it now... its a jquery based absolute positioning plugin :)